# Ember.Map.create() -> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to get the ember-datastore running (https://github.com/emberjs/data) - but the initial call of

```
window.App.store = DS.Store.create
  revision: 3,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({ bulkCommit: false })
```

already fails with an undefined-exception in:

```
DS.Transaction = Ember.Object.extend({
  init: function() {
   set(this, 'buckets', {
       clean:   Ember.Map.create(),
```

I have found some docs on the the Ember.Map (http://ember-apis.herokuapp.com/symbols/*global*.html), but it does not look like it's defined in the ember-namespace of the version I am using.

I'm using:

- ember-rails: https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails
- ember-data: https://github.com/emberjs/data

I built ember-data (using rake dist) and included it - does it expect any other version of ember than the one that comes with ember-rails?

Answer (score 0):

`Ember.Map` is available since commit [1296814](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/12968146f75bf3c5a625df1268dca5433278673f#packages/ember-runtime/lib/system/map.js). Are you using Ember.js version 0.9.5? There is an `ember-latest.js` available for [download](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/downloads).

Comment: solved it: The reason here is, that ember-rails uses an ember-distributions from 2 months ago, that did not yet include the Map. I forked ember-rails (https://github.com/mugwump/ember-rails) and updated the packaged ember.js to a current build of ember, now the Map can be found and the data-store works.

Please use this fork at your own risk: Apart from the Map, it introduces lots of breaking changes (e.g. the SC-Namespace is finally gone) and is not yet thoroughly tested...